# Why don't constraints "work" anymore when changing the frame of a view?

Tags: ios, objective-c

When I'm trying to change the size of the frame a `UIWebView`, it changes, but the constraints that were related to this view are ignored. here is a screenshot:
[link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IDKFH.png).

As you can see, the webview goes on the button, and the vertical space constraint is ignored.

Here is the code for changing the frame:

```
-(void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView{
    CGRect frame = _webview.frame;
    frame.size.height = 1;
    _webview.frame = frame;
    CGSize fittingSize = [_webview sizeThatFits:CGSizeZero];
    frame.size = fittingSize;
    _webview.frame = frame;
}
```

What am I missing? What should I change to make it work?

Comment: i think you want to set your web view content view according to incoming data from link??

Comment: Yep, but no problem with this, it's the button that goes under the webview, like in the picture.

Answer (score 1):

Below are the steps.

1) Remove bottom constraints of the button. Give it height constraint.

2) Update height constraint of the web view instead of updating frame.

Hope this helps!

Comment: If I have many views below the webview, will I have to give each one a height?

Comment: And another thing - All those view are on a UIScrollView, so I think I must have a bottom constraint for the last items (the button) otherwise it doesn't scroll. Right?

Comment: Yes, you have to give bottom constraint. Button, ImageView, UILabel can use intrinsic sizes. So, If there are many views, you should use intrinsic size.

Comment: I don't understand, is your method supposed to work even on a scrollview? because you're telling me to remove the bottom constraint, but saying that I must have it, could you please explain?

Answer (score 0):

In your case `webview` changes its height accordingly but it overrides the `button` so if you are changing the height of `webview` dynamically so you must have to update  the `contraints` of other `UI` components below it according to the hierarchy.

Comment: Isn't there another way? Is it because it's a webview? or would be the same with any view?

Comment: using `autoresize` or `programatically` setting constant x y position many ways now its up to you .. :)

Comment: I'm looking for a way in the storyboard, telling the webview not to "override" the button, I tried for example setting the priority of the bottom constraint to be low. It didn't help. You got another idea?